# How to count rows in GridView using webdriver c#, how to translate the existing protractor script to c# webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, protractor

I am trying to count the rows of the table and below is the HTML:
[image: my html]

I want to get the total count rows of the table, discarding table header and expanded row. I had tried the code below:

```
var altrowCount = driver.FindElement(By.Id("resultsRepeaterGrid")).FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).Count;
```

Now I realized it is counting all the tr. Hoping to get some input from who had experienced this. Thanks!

I had a working protractor script which was

```
searchResCount = element.all(by.css('#resultsRepeaterGrid tr[class="row"], tr[class="altrow"]'));
```

Now how do I translate this syntax to c# webdriver language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To translate your protractor script use the same css selector:

```
int searchResCount = driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("#resultsRepeaterGrid tr[class="row"], tr[class="altrow"]")).Count;
```

Comment: what happened was, it counted all tr that can be found in the HTML. What I wanted is to only count the occurrences of  the classes 'altrow' and 'row' and maybe add them up. I had a working protractor script which is this: searchResCount = element.all(by.css('#resultsRepeaterGrid tr[class="row"], tr[class="altrow"]')); I am not sure how to translate to C# webdriver language

Comment: I'm not sure what is your goal, but if you have working protractor script it should be easy to change it to C# webdriver. Try with the same css selector: `driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("#resultsRepeaterGrid tr[class="row"], tr[class="altrow"]")).Count`